# Reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy

How does reverse proxy server work? Is it used to secure the main server? Is it used as a firewall? What are the reasons for using a proxy server? Could someone give a real world example?

Comment: I could not give a more complete answer then what's available here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Answer (score 11):

Typically a normal proxy server looks at requests going from an internal network out to the internet and caches them so that if another client requests the same page, the proxy can give it to them much quicker than a brand new request to a remote server.

A reverse proxy works in the opposite way.

Generally a reverse proxy will be installed in front of a web server, so that the second time a client requests a page from that server, the proxy will give it back to the remote client without bothering the web server at all.

In many cases the reverse proxy and the web server are the same machine.  This is often done because the work the reverse proxy does is much, much simpler than going through a complete web server transaction.

Apache, lighthttpd and many other web servers can also function as reverse proxies.

Check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for real world implemention in .NET, there is [.NET URL Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.sourceforge.net/), a free open-source component for IIS/ASP.NET.

As the name suggests, it's an URL rewriting component, but it has **also reverse proxying capabilities**.

With a simple line like this in the configuration file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.testsiteXY.com$1 [P]
```

you could easily distribute sites to internal or external locations.

Comment: Huh? Downvote to -1? This is a real world example of a reverse proxy, which I use in a production system...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can only guess that the downvoter had heard of mod_rewrite, but did not realize it could point to external domains.

Answer (score 0):

“A proxy server is a go‑between or intermediary server that forwards requests for content from multiple clients to different servers across the Internet. A reverse proxy server is a type of proxy server that typically sits behind the firewall in a private network and directs client requests to the appropriate backend server. A reverse proxy provides an additional level of abstraction and control to ensure the smooth flow of network traffic between clients and servers.”[[see]](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/)

“Having a point at which you can inspect, transform and route HTTP requests before they reach your web servers provides a whole host of benefits.” [[see]](https://dzone.com/articles/benefits-reverse-proxy)

Common uses for a reverse proxy server include:

- Load Balancing
- Security
- Centralized authentication
- Caching
- Compression